# FRC (Ribbon Cable) vs CAT6 Cable Signal Integrity

Tags: pcb-design, connector, signal-integrity

How bad would a 10-pin FRC perform w.r.t. a CAT6 cable in terms of signal integrity? I know CAT6 is any day superior, but I want to know by how much.

Using CAT6 has been a pain for me. Crimping those Ethernet Jack connectors, even the pass-through ones, is a pain. Many times the crimping doesn't happen properly, or my crimping tool is of low quality. Many times the connector does not seat well in the RJ45 jack, or I am using low-quality 8P8Cs. In any case, good-quality connectors are not available around me. Another problem is that RJ45 jacks take up a lot of space on the PCB. Compared to a 10-pin FRC header, it's twice the size, and 8-layer PCB real estate here is costly AF.

My cable will carry one set of motor step dir pulses running at 1MHz from a SN75176 driver, i.e. CW+, CW- ,CC+ CC-, one set of Modbus running also driven by SN75176, i.e. RS485+, RS485-, one low-speed GPIO going through an optocoupler, i.e. FAULT+, FAULT- (in the case of CAT6, this set is omitted since 2 pins are less on the connector), and finally a 24V and a ground. The length of the cable is around 1 metre. The environment is noisy.

I have used CAT6 in my current prototype; it runs fine when everything is done properly, or else it becomes a nightmare. To save PCB space, I decided to think about FRC; crimping it seems easy enough, and the connector also seats the RJ45 way better. FRC seems like a nice idea to use for convinence. BUT I have concerns about how bad will it perform in the signal integrity.

Thanks

EDIT: When I say FRC I mean the standard IDC Flat Ribbon Cable that used to go into PATA slots of old Hard Drives and CD/Drives of older computers before SATA was adopted. I do not know its technical name.

Comment: Ribbon goes a long way, **if** you organize the pinout properly. Apart from low speed signals like status flags, I try to keep a signal return wire between each signal wire. This is probably overkill, but I use them mainly for convenience, not for density. For all of your use cases, ribbon will be absolutely fine.

Comment: CAT6 is a specification for cables. FRC is a cable, and there are many kinds of them with different specifications, even twisted pair and shielding. It is impossible to say how any random FRC compares to a CAT6 cable. And when you have a specification for the FRC cable, you can compare it with CAT6.

Comment: Bubu, I find @tobalt 's answer about right. It's how I handle things without wanting to get into numbers. Basically? \$1\:\text{MHz}\$ is not a problem area. So if that's your region, I'd just go with what tobalt indicated. It is when things get an order of magnitude, or two, more that I begin to worry. But you are in safe territory.

Comment: I once switched a 1 m cable RJ45 motor controller with a 4 MHz bandwidth to individual twisted pairs and a terminal block. The idea was to avoid the annoying RJ45 cabling while allowing reordering the pairs for different motors and retain 100 ohm differential impedance. It worked great even in a relatively noisy environment.

Comment: If the environment is particularly noisy, you might try twisted pair flat ribbon cable. It has areas of where there are no twists, so you can use insulation displacement connectors, but has the twists, so if you use differential signaling, you get good noise rejection.

Comment: I see, thanks for your input guys. @tobalt Yes I was going to order the the differential plus and minus adjecently for better signal integrity. If you suggest this is overkill I assume going ahead with FRC shouldn't be a problem then.

Comment: I would recommend keeping the pairs on adjacent wires in the ribbon, with GND wires between all separate functions.  Like this:  G,CW+,CW-,G....

The idea being that both wires in each pair will be subject to substantially the same common-mode interference, and the differential receiver will ignore that.  

It is best to have at least one return wire (GND) adjacent to each signal wire if you have the pins.

Comment: @Bubu Regarding your edit, there is no "standard flat ribbon cable". There are many kinds and each with different parameters (current, voltage, color, size, official approvals from safety labs depending on if you need them if you are going to sell your product with some safety compliance). Pick one that fits your needs, but there are also ones with more precise materials to guarantee some impedance etc.